# Shopware: How to add data from M:N table to product entity

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to add new data to the product entity based on the guide [Add complex data to existing entites](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities.html) but I'm struggling to find the right approach.

To be precise, I have a mapping table with columns `product_id`, `category_id`, `product_version_id`, `category_version_id`, and more fields to store information about the product-category relation, e.g. `position` which describes the current position of a product in a certain category. But it seems to be impossible to retrieve this information as no additional filter can be applied internally in the left join section.

My entity definition currently defines these fields:

```php
protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
    return new FieldCollection([
        (new FkField('product_id', 'productId', ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
        (new ReferenceVersionField(ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
        (new FkField('category_id', 'categoryId', CategoryDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
        (new ReferenceVersionField(CategoryDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
        new IntField('position', 'position'),
        new ManyToOneAssociationField('product', 'product_id', ProductDefinition::class, 'id', false),
        new ManyToOneAssociationField('category', 'category_id', CategoryDefinition::class, 'id', false),
    ]);
}
```

My extension is similar to the `product.categoriesRo` field and currently looks like this:

```php
public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
{
    $field = new ManyToManyAssociationField('pcd', CategoryDefinition::class, MyProductCategoryDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'category_id');
    $field->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(false), new WriteProtected());
    $collection->add($field);
}
```

When I subscribe to event `sales_channel.product.process.criteria`, the filter for `product.categoriesRo` is already set. However, it seems impossible to join the information from my table. It should create internally this join:

```sql
...
LEFT JOIN product_category_data` pcd ON product.id = pcd.product_id
    AND product.version_id = pcd.product_version_id
    AND pcd.category_id = `product.categoryRo`.`id`
    AND pcd.category_version_id = :category_version_id
```

I already checked the AssociationFields and their [resolver](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/tree/trunk/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Dbal/FieldResolver) but could not find a solution to my problem. Is there a different field type I could use? Or do I really need to implement a new field resolver like OneToManyAssociationFieldResolver to apply a contextual filter? I have the feeling that this question is so generic that it should be possible in Shopware core for other M:N tables, like additional data for the product_tag or sales_channel_payment_method tables.